Create an interface for a subset of JSX.Elements / ReactElement
I would like to group all my icons, so I created an IconInterface
import { IconProps, CaretProps, CheckboxProps } from "./IconProps";

interface IconInterface {
    (props: IconProps | CaretProps | CheckboxProps): JSX.Element;
}

export default IconInterface;

and applied it to my icons like like:
const BarChart: IconInterface = function ({ id, handleClick, useSpan }: IconProps) {
    return (
        <IconContainer id={id} handleClick={handleClick} useSpan={useSpan}>
            <svg>
              // svg code
            </svg>

        </IconContainer>
    );
};

export default BarChart;

But I was hoping to be able to then have the Button element to only accept icons, so I tried:
interface ButtonProps {
    icon?: ReactElement
    ...
}

and I was hoping to be able to, in the render method, do something like
icon ?? (icon)

But that just errors as IconInterface is not of the appropriate type:
TS2322: Type IconInterface | undefined is not assignable to type
string | number | boolean | ReactElement<any, string | JSXElementConstructor<any>> | Iterable<ReactNode> | ReactPortal | null | undefined

I tried to make IconInterface extend ReactElement, but I was unsuccessful, I don't see how to make those match. Is there any way I could do this? I don't want the Button to accept any ReactElement as the icon prop, I would really like it to only accept icons.


Your question formatting seems to be broken, and you should probably add a little more context of the render function. -- 2. icon ?? icon can return undefined, therefore the type is IconInterface | undefined, which is not assignable to IconInterface. Make sure to to handle the undefined case. E.g. accept an undefined, or don't execute that part of code if icon is undefined.


Thank you. I just fixed the formatting and posted the solution I ended up implementing, I don't know why I hadn't seen this comment until now

I figured it out on myself some days after I posted the question, I hadn't seen @kca's comment at the time, but it's correct the undefined had to be taken into account.
interface IconInterface {
    (props: IconProps | CaretProps | CheckboxProps): ReactElement;
}

export default IconInterface;

I applied it to the icons similarly to the way I had in the question:
const BarChart: IconInterface = function ({ id, handleClick, useSpan }: IconProps) {
    return (
        <IconContainer id={id} handleClick={handleClick} useSpan={useSpan}>
            <svg>
              // svg code
            </svg>

        </IconContainer>
    );
};

export default BarChart;

Then I was able to use it on the Button props like
interface ButtonProps {
    icon?: IconInterface;

and then use it in the Button component method like
const iconElement = icon !== undefined ? (icon()) : null
  return (
    // other code
    {iconElement}
    // more code 
  );

